# code to delete customer, addresses and related orders in magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento, do we have option to delete customer along with his addresses and orders with php code? If yes, I want to know the php code. I know that, from Admin we have option to delete customers. But we need php code or query to do this process manually. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a standalnoe script on magento root folder with the following code:

```
<?php
include_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$customerId = 10;  // Here you can specify customer ID

Mage::register('isSecureArea', TRUE);

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);

$orderIds = array();        
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderIds[] = $order->getId();      
}

foreach($orderIds as $id){
    try{
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id)->delete();
        echo "order #".$id." is Deleted <br>";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "order #".$id." could not be Deleted: ".$e->getMessage() ."<br>";
    }
}

try{
    Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customerId)->delete();
    echo "Customer #".$customerId." Deleted Successfully <br>";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Customer #".$customerId." could not be Deleted: ".$e->getMessage() ."<br>";
}



Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');

die('Deletion DONE');
```

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 0):

To Delete customer's details and Orders:

Create a file with any name like Test.php with the below code in the root folder

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);

$customerId = 'xxx'; // put your customer id
$orders = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);
$orderIds = array();   

foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderIds[] = $order->getId();      
}

foreach($orderIds as $id){
    try{
        $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id)->delete();
        echo "order #".$id." is Deleted <br>";
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "order #".$id." could not be Deleted: ".$e->getMessage() ."<br>";
    }
}

try{
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository')->deleteById($customerId);
        echo 'Deleted Customer for Id : ' . $customerId . ' ' ; 
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Customer #".$customerId." could not be Deleted: ".$e->getMessage() ."<br>";
}
```

Hope it will help you...!